# cd into first 'find' result (even if path contains spaces)

Tags: linux, bash, find

I want to cd into the first result from a call to `find` (Linux bash).

#### Problem

Directories within the result path contain space characters

#### My solution (not working)

```
cd $(find -iname <my search pattern> -type d | head -1)
```

=> I skimmed through the `-printf` options of `man find` but didn't find anything.

**Is there a way to get an escaped path as result from `find` so that `cd` can operate on this path even if the dir names contain spaces?**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: use quotes: `cd "$(find ...)"`

Comment: His command wont work because head will display '.' as first result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a bash expert so I don't know if this is a good solution but what seems to work is:

```
cd "`find -iname <my search pattern> -type d | head -1`"
```

The back ticks allow you to execute commands within a string.